# How to calculate data by constructed neural network toolbox?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a series of x and y data. For Example:

```
x=[1 2 4 5 7 8 9 18 29]
y=[4 7 11 18 35 42 67 100 110]
```

I have used Neural-Network toolbox of Matlab and have made a neural network model.(I have put my codes in the end of question)
But I want to calculate corresponding values of below x.In other word,if:

```
x=[60 80 98 120]
```

then,I want to calculate corresponding y of this points in Matlab?(I know that I can do this calculation by simple regression.But I insist on doing this by neural network)

Can anyone help me?

```
x=[1 2 4 5 7 8 9 18 29]
y=[4 7 11 18 35 42 67 100 110]

%// Solve an Input-Output Fitting problem with a Neural Network
%// Script generated by NFTOOL
%// Created Wed Oct 15 00:18:47 PDT 2014
%//
%// This script assumes these variables are defined:
%//
%//   x - input data.
%//   y - target data.

inputs = x;
targets = y;

%// Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

%// Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
%// For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};


%// Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
%// For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  %// Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'sample';  %// Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

%// For help on training function 'trainlm' type: help trainlm
%// For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';  %// Levenberg-Marquardt

%// Choose a Performance Function
    %// For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'mse';  %// Mean squared error

%// Choose Plot Functions
%// For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};


%// Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

%// Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

%// Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs)

%// View the Network
view(net)

%// Plots
%// Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%//figure, plotperform(tr)
%//figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%//figure, plotfit(net,inputs,targets)
%//figure, plotregression(targets,outputs)
%//figure, ploterrhist(errors)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code - care to be specific about what/where the problem is?

Comment: Also did you at least try `net([60 80 98 120])`?

Comment: You are right that logistic regression fits better this problem. Besides, you are trying to extrapolate and NN's cannot.

Answer (score 2):

There is an specific function in maltab to simulate trained NN: [`sim`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/nnet/ref/sim.html)

Its as easy as:

```
    sim(net,x);

ans =

  102.6437  102.6437  102.6437  102.6437
```

it will simulate the network given the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Ander Biguri is the correct one. I just want to insist of two problems about your approach (this could be a comment and blabla, but I couldn't include a picture)

If you see your predicted points (red crosses), they look fine.

[image]

However, if you plot the predicted points for all the x-axis, you can see what the NN actually learnt from your data:

[image]

```
x_ = 0:0.1:120;
y_ = sim(net,x_);
figure;
hold on;
plot(x_,y_,'r.');
plot(x,y,'bo');
axis([0 100 0 300]);
```

You can spot two issues:

1. The NN is overfitting because of the lack of data. Besides, the non-linear hyperplane of the NN gets crazy.
2. The NN's cannot extrapolate. All the predicted value greater that `x=29` have non-sense.

Answer (score 0):

Note that test range *x=[60 80 98 120]* is well outside training range *x=[1 2 4 5 7 8 9 18 29]*. So what we're trying to do here is to: **Solve Extrapolation using ANN & Not using ANN for its purpose that is Classification**.

In simple words *for extrapolation use curve fitting like regression not ann* or *use ann with custom neurons*. If ann is mandate than use entire data range to train *x=[1 2 4 5 7 8 9 18 29 60 80 98 120]* the network.